# Python: 'q)+' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, stdin

Python newbie here.

I have a program named `zeroOrMore.py`

It reads a regular expression (regex) from stdin.

I invoke the program like this:

```
python zeroOrMode.py (ab)*(p|q)+
```

That results in this error message:

```
'q)+' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I discovered that if I enclose the regex in double quotes:

```
python zeroOrMode.py "(ab)*(p|q)+"
```

then there is no error.

Is there a way to accomplish this without wrapping the regex in double quotes? Here's how my program inputs the regex:

```
regex = sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: The pipe `|` has a specific meaning on the command line, so the quotes are non-optional. Why don't you want to include them?

Comment: This is bash interpreting the pipe `|` as an operator, and only passing python the `(ab)*(p` (it might expand the `*` as well, actually). Basically, no, there's no way.

Comment: You need to use double quotes. This is actually pretty common. You would encounter a similar problem if this string had a space or if this commandline argument represented a file name with a space. So by using the double quotes. It is better to conform to the expected norm than to try and find a way around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't Python; it's CMD. The regex you're giving to Python is being interpreted by the command prompt first. The pipe (`|`) is the batch command for piping input to the following program. Basically, CMD is reading the command line like so:

```
python zeroOrMode.py (ab)*(p    |    q)+
```

It's trying to take the result of running `zeroOrMode.py` (I think you meant more?) with `(ab)*(p` and piping the output to the (nonexistent) program `q)+`.

There isn't really much of a solution to this, unfortunately. You could always escape the pipe like so:

```
python zeroOrMode.py (ab)*(p^|q)+
```

The caret (`^`) will cause any special meanings the next character has to be ignored.